# Выровнять вывод по левому краю

Tags: java, строки

Как выровнять текст по левому краю, чтобы не было так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно было бы поставить перед строкой `"\t"` но это четыре пробела, а нужно один или два.

```java
public static String toString(Map map) {
    System.out.print("{");
    for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
        Integer value = (Integer) map.get(key);

        System.out.println("\t" + key + ":" + " " + value);
        System.out.println("}");
        return map.toString();
```

Comment: Не совсем верно задал вопрос. Вывод идет в цикле.

Comment: Покажите весь код

Comment: Это не весь код. Изментие вопрос чтобы он содержал код.

Comment: У меня все выводится ровно, возможно это проблема вывода вашего JDK.  Кстати после второго вывода должна стоять `}`

Comment: С применением \t отступ будет ровный, да, но это 4 пробела. А как сделать заданное количество пробелов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассчитывать на то, что символ `\t` соответствует 4 пробелам также нельзя, так как эта настройка конфигурируется и *часто* табуляция равна 8 пробелам.

Для решения "проблемы" достаточно выводить содержимое мапы с новой строки между парой символов `"{}"`.

Также представленный код следует улучшить:

1. использовать *типизированную* мапу, а не сырую, с последующим явным приведением типа
2. Оставить одну определённую функцию для метода `toString(Map)`: либо только напечатать содержимое заданной мапы, либо как-то преобразовать мапу в несколько строк нужного формата.

- Метод для печати мапы

```java
public static<K, V> void printMap(Map<K, V> map) {
    System.out.println('{');
    for (K key : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.print("  "); // желаемые два пробела
        System.out.print(key);
        System.out.print(": ");
        System.out.println(map.get(key));
    }
    System.out.println('}');
}
```

Аналогичный метод для получения многострочного представления:

```java
public static<K, V> String toString(Map<K, V> map) {
    if (map.isEmpty()) {
        return "{}";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('{').append(System.lineSeparator());

    for (K key : map.keySet()) {
        sb.append("  ").append(key).append(": ").append(map.get(key))
          .append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    sb.append('}').append(System.lineSeparator());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Также можно использовать Stream API, в частности коллектор [`Collectors.joining(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence prefix, CharSequence suffix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```java
public static<K, V> String toString(Map<K, V> map) {
    String newLine = System.lineSeparator();
    return map.isEmpty() ? "{}" : map.keySet().stream()
        .map(k -> String.format("  %s: %s", k, map.get(k))) // нужный формат
        .collect(Collectors.joining(newLine, "{" + newLine, newLine + "}"));
}
```